# 240v Garage lighting

Tags: led, garage, 240v

My Garage has four, four-bulb flourescent light fixtures (T8).  I am removing the ballasts and replacing the bulbs with LED bulbs.  No problem there. While doing this, I was surprised to discover the lights are running on 240 volts.

Is there any reason I cannot switch the double-throw breaker out for a single with a very slight rewiring at the breaker box and recover a breaker slot in my main panel?

Comment: Is there anything else on this circuit?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.  More investigation will happen before I attempted such a change.

Answer (score 1):

If they are the only loads on the circuit, that should be easily do-able, assuming that the wiring is cable with white as L2. If it's /3 with black, white, red, ground, get highly suspicious of the potential for other loads wired as an MWBC, but if you don't find them it should still be easily done.

If conduit as hot-hot-ground, you'll have to pull a white or grey neutral, you cannot repurpose any other color as neutral. If there's already a neutral, no problem beyond the prior warning to look very carefully for other loads (that could be 120V if there is a neutral, indicating an MWBC.)

You can, of course, get 240V LEDs, but you seem to be interested in gaining a breaker panel space, so not the way you'd want to go.

Comment: There are no red wires, simply black, white and ground (bare copper).  I don't think there are any other loads  on it, but I'll be verifying.  I basically need to map the entire panel and sub-panel because it's such a fiasco.  I only found out it was 240, because I bought LEDs (and already started the process). Fortunately they're rated for 120-277v, because I never considered that lights would be running 240v.

Comment: Then it  should be an easy change!